# Clockpicker: How to prevent click on input to open clockpicker

Tags: jquery, html, clock

I'm using [weareoutman's clockpicker](https://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/) on my page. How to prevent click on input to show clockpicker or fade in overlay before clockpicker come to visible? I just wanted to fade in overlay before clockpicker shows. Click on "button" is working as desired. So far I have tried beforeShow function in clockpicker also e.preventDefault() and e.stopPropagation() -functions in jQuery.

HTML:

```
<div class="dialog">
    <div>Clock:</div>
    <div class="input-group" id="clockpicker">
        <input type="text" id="start-time" class="clock text-right" readonly />
        <span class="button button-gray icon icon-clock"></span>
    </div>
<div class="dialog-overlay hide"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var clock = jQuery('#clockpicker'),
    dialog_overlay = jQuery('.dialog-overlay');

clock.clockpicker({
    autoclose: true,
    afterDone: function() {
        dialog_overlay.fadeOut('slow');
    }
});

clock.on('click', function(e) {
    dialog_overlay.fadeIn('slow', function() {
        clock.clockpicker('show');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution to the problem. Set click event off in input field.

```
clock.find('input').off('focus.clockpicker click.clockpicker');
```

I hope that this solution helps someone else also.

Answer (score 0):

With recent versions of library you can do something like this:

```
$('#inputId').clockpicker({
        beforeShow: function e() {            
            var condition = "...";
            if (!condition) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
        }            
    });
```