# How to avoid displaying the bootstrap clockpicker when its input is disabled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, clockpicker

I'm using the [clockpicker](https://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/) plugin in a page the clock can be enabled or disabled dinalically without reloading the entire page. So, when I load the page I initialize only if its enabled.

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
    configureClockPickers();
});

function configureClockPickers(){
    $('.clockpicker').each(function(){
        $(this).clockpicker({autoclose: true});
    }
}
```

if the input is dinamically enabled (calling again to my function configureClockPickers() the clock is displayed perfectly.

Problem appears when the inputs is dinalically disabled. I don't know how to stop displaying the clock when the clock icon is clicked (if the disabled input is clicked no clock is displayed).

My clock is generated as follows:

```
<div id="clock" class="input-group clockpicker" data-placement="left" data-align="top">
    <form:input path="clock1" id="clock1" type="text" cssClass="form-control inputForm inputClock"/>    
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span></span>
</div>
```

Any idea?

Thank you so much!

Comment: I have solved here!!! : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34978129/clockpicker-how-to-prevent-click-on-input-to-open-clockpicker/47032514#47032514

Answer (score 0):

When you disable inputs, you need also to prevent bubbling of the `click` event from `span`. Something like this:

```
var inpDisabled;

$('.clockpicker .input-group-addon').on('click', function (e) {
    if(inpDisabled){
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});

//...
//somewhere in the code

inpDisabled = true;
```

After that your `.clockpicker` will not hear `click` events from nested `span` and will not show the picker

**This is a general solution, so you need to transform it on your custom project**

Comment: Not working for me... I've tried even to disable the 'click' always but the clockpicker still appears. I've written this in my onready (and console displays "hello" and the clockpicker after that :(     $('.clockpicker .input-group-addon').on('click', function (e) { console.log("hello!"); e.stopPropagation(); 
 });